# Reformatting text file

Tags: python, awk, sed

I want to reformat one text file, so every paragraph will have approximately 150 characters.
After deleting all \n characters we have one long line.

```
Input:
1 Line

Output:
Every first blank after every 150 characters to be replaced with \n
```

Comment: if it is supposed to be a paragraph it would make more sense to insert a newline after the first fullstop past 150 characters

Comment: What you have [tried yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: yes, it have sense @james-kent

Comment: but in that case, some sentence can break approx 150 characters separating by dots (some long sentence) @james-kent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(.\{128\}.\{22\}[^ ]*\) /\1\
/g' YourFile
```

128 than 22 due to limitation of posix sed to 128 char per repetition (GNU sed should directly accept 150)

Comment: sed 's/\\(.\{150\}[^ ]*\\) /\1\n/g' YourFile is correct sed, but for idea, answer is accepted!

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to try fold:

```
fold -s -w 150 filename
```

Answer (score 1):

you really should post some code of what you've tried on here rather than essentially asking other people to do it for you, but here is a snippet that should do something like what you want and break after the first fullstop:

```
inputline = "somelongstring"
outputline = ""

count = 0

for character in inputline: #iterate through the line
    count += 1 #increment the counter on each loop
    if count >= 150: #check counter
        if character == ".": #if fullstop then add fullstop and newline to output
            outputline += ".\n"
            count = 0 #reset counter
        else:
            outputline += character #otherwise pass character to output
    else:
        outputline += character #otherwise pass character to output
```